# Don't understand rewrite rule involving query string parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My menu links to internal sites via

```
<a href="<?php $PHP_SELF ?>?site=company">
```

`index.php` includes the content in this way:

```
if ($_GET['site']=="company") {
    include'sites/company.php';
}
```

So far so good. Now I searched for hours and tried a lot of stuff to rewrite the address from `/index.php?site=company` to `/company`. Nothing takes effect. One of the attempts:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/?([\w]+)? /index.php?site=$1
```

Can anybody help, please? I´m new to `.htaccess`.

Comment: You are aware that using mod_rewrite does not change your HTML code, right? If you want the browser to request `/company`, then the first thing you have to do is change that in your link accordingly …

Comment: Keep your links as: `<a href="/company">`

Comment: Yes, i´m aware of that. Keeping the link like your hint isn´t so easy because the index.php gives the "frame" with menus, banners, footer ... and only loads the php-file as content.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether it is “easy” (for you) or not – without links in your HTML code that have the desired format it makes no sense trying to rewrite the requests reaching the server, because there _is_ nothing to rewrite in that case.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, but I have no static links because content loads dynamic. I´m a little confused about your statement.
What´s the way to get "speaking URLs" in that case? Many sites (and CMSs) working with dynamic SEO-links without static pages I think.
Thanks in advance